# $L^2$-valued integral as parameter integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

### Setting

Let us regard the Hilbert space $L^2(0,1)$ and the $C_0$-semigroup $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ defined by
$$
T(t):\left\{
\begin{array}{rml}
L^2(0,1) & \to & L^2(0,1), \\
f &\mapsto &\left(x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
f(x+t), & \text{if}\; x+t<1\\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\right).
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It is easy to verify that this is indeed a $C_0$-semigroup. Therefore, the mapping $t \mapsto T(t)f$ is a continuous mapping from $L^2(0,1)$ to $L^2(0,1)$. Consequently the $L^2(0,1)$-valued integral
$$
g := \int_0^1 T(t)f \,\mathrm{d}t
$$
exists.

### Question

In order to get some information about the behavior of $g$ it would be nice to regard $g$ as a parameter integral. Hence I am interested in the following equality
$$
g(x) = \Big(\int_0^1 T(t)f \,\mathrm{d}t\Big) (x)\stackrel{?}{=} \int_0^1 \big(T(t)f\big)(x)\,\mathrm{d}t
.
$$
Or with a different notation
$$
g = 
\int_0^1 \big(x \mapsto \big(T(t)f\big)(x) \big)\,\mathrm{d}t
\stackrel{?}{=}
\Big(x\mapsto\int_0^1 \big(T(t)f\big)(x)\,\mathrm{d}t\Big)
.
$$
The evaluation mapping is neither continuous nor well-defined on $L^2$. So I think it is not trivial to justify this step.

It seems quite common to evaluate such $L^2(0,1)$-valued integrals by interpreting it as a parameter integral, so I guess that there is a theorem which justifies that. It would be really great if someone had a reference.

### Solution for this special case

In this particular case I think I have a solution. I know that every convergent sequence in $L^2$ has a subsequence which converges even point-wise a.e.. Since
$$
g_n := x\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \Big(T\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)f\Big)(x)
$$
converges to $g$ and every subsequence of $g_n(x)$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ to the same limit for a.e. $x\in (0,1)$, the point-wise limit of $g_n$ has to coincide with $g$ a.e..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$
$$
    g(x) = \int_{0}^{1}(T(t)f)(x)\d t=\int_{0}^{1-x}f(x+t)\d t=\int_{x}^{1}f(y)\d y.
$$
You may use a Riemann integral for the function $t\mapsto T(t)f$ because it is a continuous function with respect to the $L^2$ norm. The resulting integral is in $L^2$. So, the following holds for al $h\in L^2$ because it holds for the Riemann sums in $t$:
$$
    \langle g,h\rangle = \Big\langle \int_{0}^{1}T(t)f \d t,h\Big\rangle \\
     = \int_{0}^{1}\langle T(t)f,h\rangle \d t
$$
Then the above may be written as
$$
   \langle g,h\rangle =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\chi_{[0,1]}(x+t)f(x+t)h(x)\d x \d t \\
  =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\chi_{[0,1]}(x+t)f(x+t)\d t\, h(x)\d x \\
  =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-t}f(x+t)\d t\, h(x)\d x \\
  =\Big\langle \int_{0}^{1-t}f(x+t)\d t,h\Big\rangle.
$$
This holds for all $h\in L^2$, which gives
$$
           g(x) = \int_{0}^{1-x}f(x+t)\d t,\;\; a.e. x.
$$

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek : The evaluation mapping is continuous and well-defined.

Comment: the first equality is the core of my question. There is no justification for this step in your answer...

Comment: The function $t\mapsto T(t)f$ is continuous from $[0,\infty)$ to $L^2$. So you use a vector Riemann integral on this function. Knowing this, you can apply a continuous linear functional $\Phi$ to both sides in order to conclude that $\Phi(g) = \int_{0}^{1}\Phi(T(t)f)dt$. And you know the form of such functionals as integrals. And that will give it.

Comment: I feel like you didn't read my question. You just repeated what I already mentioned and changed that the evaluation mapping is conitinuous on $L^2$ which is definitive wrong.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek : I've offered a careful treatment for you. Take another look.

Comment: I think this answers my problem. I only have to check if Fubini doesn't make any problems. The rest seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek : You're welcome.